# new c++11 for loop causes: "error: ‘begin’ was not declared in this scope"

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to learn c++, so I wrote a short program that uses the new c++11 for loop, which makes the compiler give me an error I don't understand. 
this is my c++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

float legge_oraria_moto_accelerato(float a[3]){
    return a[2]*a[0] + 0.5*a[1]*a[0]*a[0];
}
int corri(float (f)(float array[3]), float arrays[3][3])
    { for(auto i:arrays) cout << f(i) << '\n';
    return 0;
} 

int main()
{ 
return 0;
}
```

and this is the compiler's (g++ -std=gnu++11) error:

```
mezzo.cpp: In function ‘int corri(float (*)(float*), float (*)[3])’:
mezzo.cpp:9:18: error: ‘begin’ was not declared in this scope
     { for(auto i:arrays) cout << f(i) << '\n';
                  ^
mezzo.cpp:9:18: note: suggested alternatives:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/basic_string.h:42:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/string:52,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/iostream:39,
                 from mezzo.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/initializer_list:89:5: note:   ‘std::begin’
     begin(initializer_list<_Tp> __ils) noexcept
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/initializer_list:89:5: note:   ‘std::begin’
mezzo.cpp:9:18: error: ‘end’ was not declared in this scope
     { for(auto i:arrays) cout << f(i) << '\n';
                  ^
mezzo.cpp:9:18: note: suggested alternatives:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/basic_string.h:42:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/string:52,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/iostream:39,
                 from mezzo.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/initializer_list:99:5: note:   ‘std::end’
     end(initializer_list<_Tp> __ils) noexcept
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/initializer_list:99:5: note:   ‘std::end’
```

Comment: As I recall, range-based for loops don't work with arrays. **Edit** OK, they should, see my comment below.

Comment: @Biffen: What makes you think so?

Comment: @bitmask Er, I went to look it up now, and apparently it *should* work, but I seem to recall having the same problem before. Maybe it's a limitation of the compiler.

Comment: Why do you have three indentation styles, all of them bad?

Comment: @lightness big mess coming from sometimes copying my textbook style without instinctively using it and not yet having developed style habits in c++

Comment: Well please get into the habit of tidying up your code before you post it. It's just courteous! Thanks.

Answer (score 44):

Range-based for loops work with arrays, but not with pointers. The issue here is that `arrays` is actually a pointer and not an array.

When you have a function parameter that is declared as an array, it is adjusted to a pointer type. You can see this here with the parameter `float arrays[3][3]`: In the compiler error message you can see that the actual parameter type is a pointer to an array `float (*)[3]`, which can't be used with a ranged-based for loop.

If you pass the array by reference instead (`float (&arrays)[3][3]`), it won't adjusted to a pointer in this manner and will therefore work with the range-based for loop.

Comment: @bitmask this post does not claim that pointers are arrays or vice versa

Comment: The standardese for the array-to-pointer type change in function parameters is *adjusted*.

Comment: To complete this great answer.. the inside `for` should looks like `for( float (&row)[3] : arrays) cout << f(row) << '\n';` http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/affd16b1d14938e2

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit of course, without using `auto` (why don't use it, I don't know :) )

Comment: thanks a lot, very well explained, I understand the issue now. It's hard for me to get the hang of pointers and references, coming from python.

Comment: shouldn't this be accepted as an answer?