# I want to know why it can be successful with vecter but not array?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

This succeeds:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int test(vector<int> items)
{
    for (int item : items)
    {
        cout << item;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> items = { 1, 2, 3 };
    test(items);
    return 0;
}
```

This fails:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int test(int items[])
{
    for (int item : items)
    {
        cout << item;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int items[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    test(items);
    return 0;
}
```

The error message is:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int test(int*)’:
main.cpp:14:21: error: ‘begin’ was not declared in this scope
     for (int item : items)
                     ^~~~~
main.cpp:14:21: note: suggested alternatives:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/string:51:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/iostream:39,
                 from main.cpp:9:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/range_access.h:87:5: note:   ‘std::begin’
     begin(_Tp (&__arr)[_Nm])
     ^~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/range_access.h:87:5: note:   ‘std::begin’
main.cpp:14:21: error: ‘end’ was not declared in this scope
     for (int item : items)
                     ^~~~~
main.cpp:14:21: note: suggested alternatives:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/string:51:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/iostream:39,
                 from main.cpp:9:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/range_access.h:97:5: note:   ‘std::end’
     end(_Tp (&__arr)[_Nm])
     ^~~
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/range_access.h:97:5: note:   ‘std::end’
```

I found a similar problem, which explained that the program did not know the size of the array.
[How to fix for each loop in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57399767/how-to-fix-for-each-loop-in-c)

But when I tested this, it was successful:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int items[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    for (int item : items)
    {
        cout << item;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Why does this succeed without specifying the size of the array?

Comment: In the second example, `items` is a pointer, not an array. In general, it's impossible to make a function with an array parameter, that parameter will be silently replaced with a pointer parameter.

Comment: use `std::array` if you want an array with all bells and whistles added. C arrays are only for legacy code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays cannot be passed to functions by value. This signature

```
int test(int items[])
```

is equivalent to

```
int test(int* items)
```

A pointer has no `begin` nor `end` and there is no way to deduce the size of the array from the pointer alone. In your second example `items` in `main` is an array (remember: arrays are not pointers), and there is `std::begin()` and `std::end()` that takes c-arrays by reference, hence the range based loop works.

If you do take the array by reference, also your function will work as expected:

```
int test(int (&items)[3])   // now items is a reference to an array (not a pointer!)
{
    for (int item : items)
    {
        cout << item;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If you make `test` a template you could even pass arrays of different sizes, but often it is simpler to use `std::array`.

Comment: So when I pass the array in C++, it doesn't copy the array but passes the pointer, and the vector is copy the same data, right?

Comment: @Errion right. `int test(vector<int> items)` takes the vector by copy. You should pass a const reference instead `int test(const vector<int>& items)` to avoid the copy

Answer (score 1):

What is explained in the comments is true:

> it's impossible to make a function with an array parameter

because of [array to pointer decay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-to-pointer-decay), but you can have a [function with a reference-to-array parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10007986/c-pass-an-array-by-reference):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<int N>
int test(int (&items)[N]) // what an ugly syntax, isn't it?
{
    for (int item : items)
    {
        cout << item;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int items[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    test(items);
    return 0;
}
```

where the use of `N` as a template parameter is to allow the function taking arrays of any length.

I case you have to support array of only length 3, which I don't think you want to, than you can give up the template parameter:

```cpp
int test(int (&items)[3])
```

But honestly, the best suggestion is to stop using C-style arrays all together. Use [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) and [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) for fixed and variable size arrays respectively.

Comment: I was mere seconds from committing a comment to said same. nice.

Answer (score -1):

Try this in the function test :

```
int test(vector<int> items)
```

So :

```
int test(vector<int> items)
{
    for (int item : items)
    {
            cout << item;
    }
  return 0;
}
```

It returns :

```
123
```

Functions and arrays are not compatible. It's hightly recommanded to use **vectors** in parameter of a function in C++.